# Ubuntu:C++::Boost library upgrade

Tags: c++, boost

After installing Boost library using Synaptic Package Manager, the version installed is `1.42`.

If I check on boost official website, the current version is: `1.45`.

How can I upgrade to 1.45 from Synaptic package manager?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can not as the distribution usually lags behind. The best option I usually follow is to just download and compile and install it myself as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

Comment: at the moment, I am using cmake to include the boost library but it seems it always add the version from the system, how can I specify the version in the cmake build file? thanks in advance!

Comment: Never used cmake before but just seen CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH on http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables (sorry can't add links)

Comment: [Updated boost install link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/)

Answer (score 1):

It has to be packaged first (by Ubuntu).

If you want to manually install the new version I would recommend that you install it into some local directory, since installing it into the system might break a lot of applications.